# HTML / CSS multiple custom fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I just started coding HTML and I am stuck on initialization of multiple fonts.
I noticed that if you initialize multiple fonts, the only that can be used was the first initialized font.

Can anyone have some other way for multiple custom fonts in HTML.

How can I improve below code?

```html
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'a1';
    src: url('Fonts/Brillianthre.ttf') format('truetype')
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'a2';
    src: url('Fonts/ReprineatoRegular.ttf') format('truetype')
  }
  
  #a1 {
    font-family: a1;
  }
  
  #a2 {
    font-family: a2;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for the response sir... i just happen to start some long term project our teacher gave us and i want to learn in advance... could you be part of my learning sir please?.

Comment: try removing `format('truetype')` then tell me if this works

Comment: i got the same problem sir... it only uses the first font while ignoring the second...

Comment: it will be good if you could post your full css, and it will be better if you can create fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please anyone having the same problem as mine would be so careful on choosing their fonts... the solution to mine was easy, i checked the integrity of the fonts(Corruptibility) and it shows that some of my fonts had been corrupted, i can't find out why but, i managed to use it earlier. Now i got myself back to the track using other fonts...

BTW thanks to @Alaa Mh and @Sanijavaid for responding to my concern...